Whole pc black screen when rendering
I upgraded all My pc, so everything should work way better than before right ? but no it's worst,
1, everytime i open big project or press save, the software doesn't repond
2, when rendering all my pc become black and i must just restart the pc:
So, i tried rendering only with gpu, same happends,
cpu only, same happens, and same with older version
I have ryzen 9, 4060 ti, 32 go ram, my problem only happens in blender, idk what to do...
thank you for your attention

hello have you tried with an older version of the graphic card driver?

Yeah, this sounds like a GPU driver issue to me.
